# How to read 16 bit register of TDC IC using SPI in Arduino?

Tags: c, arduino, embedded, spi

I'm trying to read the default value of 0xB8 register which is supposed to be 1311 in HEX. But I get FF as response. The TDC IC I use is MAX35101. Writing and reading returns boolean 1.

Someone please check my code logic.

Below is the complete code.

```
#define SS 10                        // D14 = MCP23S08 GPIO SPI select pin
#define SCLK 13                     // D18 SPI SCLK 
#define MISO 12                     // D19 SPI MISO
#define MOSI 11                     // D23 SPI MOSI
#define RESET 0X04 //


#include <SPI.h>

bool MAX35101_Send_Opcode(char opcode);
bool MAX35101_Write_Register(char address, uint16_t DatatoWrite);
void MAX35101_Read_Register(char address, uint16_t* results);


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SPI.begin();
  pinMode(SS, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH); 
}

bool MAX35101_Send_Opcode(char Opcode)
{ 
  bool success;
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(1000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE1));
  digitalWrite(SS, LOW);
  success = SPI.transfer(Opcode);
  Serial.println(success);
  digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
  SPI.endTransaction();
}

bool MAX35101_Write_Register(char address, uint16_t DatatoWrite)// one word register only, Modulates CS# line, Sends address, reads data
{
    bool success;
    SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(1000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE1));
    digitalWrite(SS, LOW);                  //Modulate CS#
    success |= SPI.transfer(address);   //Transmit the 8 bits over the SPI Bus //OPcode address
    success |= SPI.transfer((char) (DatatoWrite >> 8)); //Transmit the 8 bits over the SPI Bus // MSB
    success |= SPI.transfer((char) (DatatoWrite & 0x00FF)); //Transmit the 8 bits over the / Bus //LSB
    digitalWrite(SS, HIGH); 
    SPI.endTransaction();                  //Modulate CS#
    //Serial.println('The write status is ' + success + '.');
    Serial.println(success);
}

void MAX35101_Read_Register(char address, uint16_t* results)//Read one word register only, Modulates CS# line, Sends address, reads data
{
    uint16_t success;
    uint16_t success_data;
    address |= 0x80;    //Read Opcodes Always have MSB of Opcode (address) Set
    SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(1000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE1));
    digitalWrite(SS, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(1);
    success = SPI.transfer(address);   //Transmit the 8 bits over the SPI Bus
    success |= SPI.transfer(results);
    digitalWrite(SS, HIGH); 
    SPI.endTransaction();
    Serial.println(success);
    //Serial.println(results);
}

unsigned long readRegister(uint8_t registerAddress) //Function for READING a selected register
{
    int registerValueR;
    registerAddress |= 0x80; 
    SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(1000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE1));
    digitalWrite(SS, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(1); 
    SPI.transfer(registerAddress);
    SPI.transfer(0x00);
    delayMicroseconds(1);
    registerValueR = SPI.transfer(0xFF);
    delayMicroseconds(1);
    digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
    SPI.endTransaction(); 
    Serial.println(registerValueR);
}

void loop()
{
  //uint16_t readData = 0;
  delay(5000);
  //MAX35101_Write_Register(0x38, 1311);
  readRegister(0xB8);
  delay(60*60*1000);
}
```

1. Tried to read 1 byte alone.
2. Tried to read 2 bytes by | ing 2 variables.

What I observe is Serial.print prints whatever I try to send as dummy byte to read the register.

Comment: SPI is full duplex, you receive at the same time as you transmit. As for what the specific IC expects in terms of timing, that's another story - and SPI is poorly standardized. Also make sure that you are using the same clock settings as the IC specifies. And finally, an oscilloscope/logic analyser is pretty much a mandatory tool when developing anything using SPI.

Comment: Understood your point. By that means, If I write SPI opcode like 0xb8 with some variable "send opcode" and again send some dummy values like "0x0" with variable "value" then should I print "send opcode" or "value" to read the register.

Answer (score 0):

Figure 14. Read Register Opcode Command Protocol on the [Datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX35101.pdf) page 26 shown that you need to send an opcode (of 0xB8) following two dummy bytes in order to read the value back, the return value is a 16-bit data (i.e. a `uint16_t` instead of a 32-bit `unsigned long`.

Here is the redefined `readRegister()` function based on the datasheet.

```cpp
uint16_t readRegister(uint8_t registerAddress)
{

    SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(1000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE1));
    digitalWrite(SS, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(1);

    // send the opcode
    SPI.transfer(registerAddress | 0x80);

    // read the 16-bit data
    uint8_t byte1 = SPI.transfer(0x00);
    uint8_t byte2 = SPI.transfer(0x00);

    delayMicroseconds(1);
    digitalWrite(SS, HIGH);
    SPI.endTransaction(); 
   
    return (byte1 << 8) | byte2; 
}
```

Comment: Tried the code. Register 0xB8 gives 0, Register 0xBA gives 0 and Register 0xB9 gives "-32768" What does this mean?